# What external sensor could detect if a cd-tray had opened?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, sensor

What would be a sensor that I could use to detect if my desktop's CD tray has opened?

There are so many sensors to choose from in the Digikey catalog.

Should I use a mechanical component?

A light beam interference component?

Which one would allow me to detect if my CD tray is open such that the information can be fed into a PIC MCU?

I know I can do a system call for this sort of question, but I would prefer some sort of external sensor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a permanent magnet and a [reed switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch).

Fix the magnet on the moving part and put the [reed switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch) on the fixed part. Then monitor the reed switch with the microcontroller.

Answer (score 7):

If power consumption isn't an issue (compared to the reed switch), I think I would go with an IR LED and a phototransistor. You could either have it break the beam when it opens or when it's closed and read from the transistor on you digital in pin.

Comment: if power *is* an issue you could pulse the LED at regular intervals and read the phototransistor during the short time the LED is on. 5 pulses per second are more than enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind disassembling the drive you could look into the interlock or drive open switch, which should be fairly easy to wire in to. It may even have a pull-up, providing a logic signal directly to your device of choice.

Comment: yeah! I feel thats the easiest :)

Comment: and if needed you can use a opto-coupler for reading the signal if you have difference in voltage levels.

Comment: @Zaxx or if you wanted isolation between the computer and another system.